# Regex- for exact 6 characters, first 3 characters are can be either be SPA or BSA and last 3 are number

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write regex of exact 6 characters long, where first three characters can be either SPA or BSA and last 3 characters are numbers (0-9). Here is my regex:

```
^SPABSA[0-9]{3}$
```

Comment: Use: `^(SPA|BSA)[0-9]{3}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression `^SPABSA[0-9]{3}$` would match strings starting with `SPABSA` followed by 3 digits eg. `SPABSA123`.

As mentioned by @anubhava, replace `SPABSA` with `(SPA|BSA)` meaning: create a capture group matching `SPA` or `BSA`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UijKI6/2